# issues with Firefox and this code for Browser version

Tags: vb.net, firefox

```
        Dim browse As HttpBrowserCapabilities
        browse = Request.Browser
        Dim browser, version As String
        browser = browse.Browser.ToString
        version = browse.Version.ToString
        If browser = "IE" Then
            If version < 6.0 Then
            pnlOldVersion.Visible = True
            UpdatePanel1.Visible = False
            UpdatePanel8.Visible = False
            Else   'do nothing
        End If
```

Why would this code cause an issue with Firefox Browsers? Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Erin

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak Visual Basic, but from the error message you quoted in my other answer:

> [InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "3.6.12" to type 'Double' is not valid.]

You have a flaw in your code: You are comparing a string (created by the `toString`) with a number (the 6.0).

That works for IE, because your IE's version number is (probably) something like `7.0`. It breaks for Firefox's `3.6.12` (which can't be auto-cast into a number).

You need to cast `browse.Version` into a number rather than a string, taking the possibility of non-numbers into account. I'm sure there are standard pre-made solutions for this in the vb.net world.

Comment: If I rewrite the code so that the version is only looked at if browser type ="IE"...  If browser = "IE" Then If version < 6.0 Then do something will that remedy my situation??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim browser As HttpBrowserCapabilities = Request.Broser
Dim min As Integer = 6
Dim version As Decimal = browser.Version

If browser.Type.Substring(0, 1).Equals("I") Then 
    'browser.Type return me "InternetExplorer11"
    If version < min Then
        pnlOldVersion.Visible = True
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = False
        UpdatePanel8.Visible = False
    End If
End If
```